port 7 and port 4 in the opamp that I can't make sense of
I greet everyone in the community,
I have a sample circuit like this

and this is how I simulate it.

theoretically X and B values on paper;
X = 1.5 VOLT
B = 3 VOLT
as
But in the simulation I find the X value close, but the B value very wrong.
When I connect 14V, - 14V to port 7 and 4, I find the correct value.
The problem is this:
why do I see the correct values when I connect 14V, -14V to ports 7 and 4? so what is the difference between connecting something to ports 7 and 4 and not connecting something to ports 7 and 4?

Pin 4 and pin 7 is power to the opamp. Without them it dont work.

I understand that on paper, i.e. theoretically, the 7 and 4 pin connection is not important, but in practice it is important, right?

Yes on paper you don’t need to connect power to an opamp  in practice very important. If you don’t add power then how to expect it to amplify. You would be generating energy.
